# Shared element transition - animate only the visible part of the shared view

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm working in an app that is similar to Google Calendar...

1. There are events and when a user click one, the event grows and
   transforms into the detail view.
2. The shared views (the events) are inside a ScrollView, so at some
   point those views may be partially visible.
3. The problem is that when one partially visible View is selected, the full View 
   appears above all and then the animation runs.

Here is a capture of the problem:
[image]

What can I do to make the Transition take only the visible part of the View to animate it?

This is my transition:

```
<changeBounds xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <arcMotion android:minimumHorizontalAngle="15"
       android:minimumVerticalAngle="0"
       android:maximumAngle="90"/>
</changeBounds>
```

Comment: Can you share a simple project at github with that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Shared elements are drawn on top of the entire view hierarchy. You can disable this by setting `Window#setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false)` in your Activities, but this will result in undesired effects. More details [here](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html) and on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAbDPjhftlQ).

The better solution is to use shared elements transition between Fragments. More details [here](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb).

Comment: Even if I set setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false) the problem persist.

Comment: @OscarMéndez I am afraid, without an example project it will be difficult to help you. The only interesting parts are: the layouts of your Activities (or Fragments) and how you start them. Just create a dummy views and post them here of even better create an example project on Github.

Comment: Sure I will create a dummy project on github and expand my question.