# Android Shared element transition - prevent shared element from being drawn

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm working in a custom `Transition` to animate only the visible part of the `Shared View` in case it is partially visible.

In my case this happens because the `Shared View` is inside a `ConstraitLayout`, and the `ConstraitLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.

I mentioned this problem in another question:
[Shared element transition - animate only the visible part of the shared view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607863/shared-element-transition-animate-only-the-visible-part-of-the-shared-view)

This is the defaul `transition` choose by the system:

[image]

And this is the one where I'm working:

[image]

The animation itself works well ... But the problem is the system draws the full shared view, before the animation starts... and there is an ugly blink.

**How can I prevent that?**

I have already on my style:

`<item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>`

Comment: Could you provide a GitHub link to your project? Adding only the relevant files to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your target Activity, add an ActionBar like the one in the source Activity, so that it naturally covers the same of your shared element. 
You might need to pass extras between Activities to configure the target ActionBar.

Comment: I do not understand why I have to add the same toolbar in the target activity, besides that it is just an example, what if the View that covers the SharedView is not the Toolbar and is in another position on the screen